# How to Add scroable footer layout in navigationview tag in drawer in android?

Tags: android, navigator

```
This is drawer layout part.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include layout="@layout/main_fragment"></include>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
      <include layout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

1. Here i have add menu attribute and header layout attribute.
2. But i am not able to add unfixed footer layout.